# RewriteRule acting oddly on specific files

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm working on a website where I'd like every file ending in `/file.html` to redirect to `/file/`. What I have mostly works, but acts very oddly on only specific files. Here are a few of the odd behaviours:

`www.blah.com/about.html/` inserts an additional `/` and directs to `...com//about/`, while `...com/media.html` redirects properly to `...com/media/`.

`...com/members/login/` fails completely and directs to the file path on the server, sorta: `...com/home/iamwou5/public_html/members/login` whereas other files in the same folder such as `signup.html` redirect fine

The index of the root page `www.blah.com` redirects to `www.blah.com/index/` no matter what I do, whereas other directories display only the directory name

Here are the relevant portions of my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Forces a trailing slash to be added
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ $1/

#example.com/page will display the contents of example.com/page.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/*$ $1.html [QSA,L]

#301 from example.com/page.html to example.com/page
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have all kinds of issues if the `Multiviews` option is enabled. And it might very likely be the case here.

Make sure you use `Options -Multiviews` at the top of your `.htaccess` file.

See http://www.gerd-riesselmann.net/archives/2005/04/beware-of-apaches-multiviews/ for some info on the subject.

Comment: Hmm. That's pretty odd, I'd be interested to learn more about it. Time for some research! Your solution of disabling it worked brilliantly, it fixed all those seemingly random problems. Thanks!